# How to replace title by logo in Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design

I want to replace the title in my Toolbar by a logo like [Twitter App](https://lh3.ggpht.com/Fd9sjOix7dWiiaVtx-3lF9o96m0ST0px39sV6CsySxuuXobB_wrMBaBZApp1S9L6d0IH=h900-rw).

I think we can replace this programmatically like that :

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
mToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo);
```

But I want to replace it directly in my XML toolBar declaration, but I can't see the property `app:logo` or `android:logo`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme" />
```

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check source code of [`Toolbar`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.java#L195) and `Toolbar`'s [custom attributes](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml#L749), there are only a few attributes you can use to customize `Toolbar`, but logo is not one of them:

- titleTextAppearance
- subtitleTextAppearance
- navigationIcon
- ...

`Toolbar.setLogo(resId)` seems to be the only option at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

A toolbar contains a ViewGroup that you can populate with whatever views you wish --- you can add an ImageView there if you want a logo. Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you manually attach it to AppCompatActivity or ActionBar activity, it "becomes" an ActionBar, and then has to be manipulated using those code functions.